# How to use lambda without reassigning variables to a final variable?

Tags: java, lambda

I always have to reassign my variable to another variable marked as `final`:

```
public void method(int myvar) {

    myvar = myvar + 1;

    doSomething(myvar); //I need to change myvar before the lambda

    final int newvar = myvar; //this line is stupid
    //could be something like:
    //makefinal myvar;

    open(con -> {
        doOtherThing(newVar);
    });
}
```

Would be really great if there was another way to declare that my variable will not be changed before the `open` call.

Comment: lets say I NEED to do `myvar + 1` before `open`

Comment: In that case you should use an additional variable anyways, for the same reason as above. And lambdas explicitly only work with `final` variables.

Comment: Would be nice if I could mark myvar in a way specifically to tell it will be final before `open`, instead of assigning to another variable

Comment: That's not possible. A variable can't be made `final` subsequently.

Comment: alright. I think the main problem is the need of the `final` variable, in C# this is not needed

Answer (score 5):

You can't. This is explicitely specified in the JLS [section 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

However, you can rewrite your example to the following:

```
public void method(int myvar) {
    final int newvar = myvar + 1;
    doSomething(newvar);
    open(con -> doOtherThing(newvar));
}
```

We're simply declaring a `final` variable `newvar` that will be reused.

Comment: @melanke See my edit. I still don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A lambda may only access variables and method parameters from the enclosing context that are `final` or "effectively final".  The latter refers to variables and parameters that are never modified within their scope.  It is important to understand here that the standard is not "unchanged before the lambda is used", but rather *never* changed after its value is first set.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't particularly like making another variable, how about using a helper method to create/return the lambda you want to pass into `open(...)`, like so:

```
public static < T > Consumer< T > helper( IntFunction< T > func, int var ) {
    return con -> func.apply( var );
}
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
public void method( int myvar ) {
    myvar = myvar + 1;
    doSomething( myvar ); //I need to change myvar before the lambda
    open( helper( arg -> doOtherThing( arg ), myvar ) );
}
```

If I got the types wrong, you can change the functional interfaces with whatever is appropriate. Also you can probably use a method reference to pass the `doOtherThing` method into `helper(...)`.